# How to package multiple files with pyinstaller?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyinstaller

What happens is that I made a trojan along with a keylogger and a shell, what I want is to make a single executable from windows, to later run the server.
thanks for your help

Comment: Are you spreading those malwares? Spearding them are mostly illegal in a lot of countries/regions. (Of course creating them doesn't count as a crime).

Answer (score 0):

Apprently this is not supported.

Source: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1633

Screen shot from the page:

[image]

Comment: May you please put the important part of the linked webpage to your answer please? Links may die overtime.

Comment: @SteveFest Thanks for the advice, added a screen shot